Sharing part of a screen on Linux
TL;DR: RegionToShare replacement for Linux.
I have a 3440x1400 display. When sharing a screen, I am used to share FullHD so that all participants have the change to see something. I am also switching apps regularly (IDE, terminal, ...) and want to share this.
I for myself want to see the participants while sharing, thus I want to share part of my screen.
On Windows, there is RegionToShare to share a screen only and FancyZones to enable good Window placement in that area.
Is there an equivalent tool for Linux?

Yes, never heard about stuff like RegionToShare, the standard is to use OBS Studio, then:

set up anything you need through its scenes, which have much wider range of possibilities than just selecting part of screen, which is doable with e.g. help of Crop filter
configure and run its virtual cam
share the virtual cam in your video conference app(s)

